# WordPress redirects to custom post single post page when trying to enter any matching letter

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have created a custom post type called institute. Here is the code for custom post type creation.

```
function register_institute_post_type()
{

    $labels = [
        "name" => __("Institute", "mgh"),
        "singular_name" => __("Institutes", "mgh"),
    ];

    $args = [
        "label" => __("Institutes", "mgh"),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Posts_Controller",
        "has_archive" => false,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "delete_with_user" => false,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => ["slug" => "institute", "with_front" => true],
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => ["title", "editor", "thumbnail", "custom-fields", "comments", "author", "page-attributes", "post-formats"],
    ];

    register_post_type("institute", $args);
}


add_action('init', 'register_institute_post_type');
```

It has created the institute post type. I have added posts to the custom post type. Now the problem is whenever I am trying any letters in the url it is automatically redirecting to the matching post details page for that institute post type.

So basically my initial setup url is like `http://localhost/instututeportal`
but whenever I am trying anything like `http://localhost/instututeportal/sa`
it is automatically redirects to

```
http://localhost/instututeportal/institute/sabanci-universitesi/
```

Here `sabanci universitesi` is a post from institute custom post type.

So can someone tell me how to show error message like 404 not found when someone tries to enter any random letters in the url? Any help and suggestions would be really appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I had to make remove_filter `redirect_canonical` and it worked finally.

`remove_filter( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );`